# Operations Research Has Graduated from Beta!

Tags: discussion

[**Official Announcement: Congratulations are in order! These sites are leaving beta**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/16/congratulations-are-in-order-these-sites-are-leaving-beta/)

---

After 900 days since the launch of our site, I'm delighted to announce that we will be leaving Beta on December 16th! This is due to the large number of questions posted, the longevity of our site and our low unanswered questions proportion.

So from that day onwards, there will be a few changes but some things will stay as they are.

- Operations Research will no longer have the Beta label attached to it. This means that we may be eligible as a migration destination from other network sites and we can potentially post community ads on our meta, where the highest-voted ads will be displayed on our main site.
- There will be a new election! [Eligible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work) community users (and current moderators) who are interested in a greater level of moderation for this site can nominate themselves, and there will be a vote after the nomination stage to decide amongst the candidates. This will occur sometime in 2022/2023.
- [Reputation thresholds](https://or.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) for privileges will remain the same.
- Site design customisation (such as logos) are not contained in this package, but they may happen at some point in the future.

Thank you to everyone for your contributions to the site, from asking questions and posting answers  to voting and editing. Special thanks to [@prubin](https://or.stackexchange.com/users/67/prubin) and [@RobPratt](https://or.stackexchange.com/users/500/robpratt) for continually providing a huge number of high-quality answers!

Comment: Woo-hoo! We're going to be gamma! Props to @LarrySnyder610 for getting the site up and running in the first place.

Comment: Congratulations! I've mostly watched this place as an outsider (while giving an occasional opinion, especially in the beginning), but I think you're having a good Q&A site here.

Comment: This will be optimal.

Comment: So the powers that be were just bluffing on the number of questions per day needing work? Or the other metrics were so good they let that one slide?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone The Area 51 statistics on 10 questions a day are extremely outdated (hardly any sites in the past couple of years have reached the metric) which is why SE is planning an overhaul in the near future.